# Yielding a block to a proc (or creating a method that accepts a block from a proc that yields)

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working on an interface that allows me to wrap arbitrary method calls with a chain of procs. Without going into too much detail, I currently have an interface that accepts something like this:

```
class Spy
  def initialize
    @procs = []
  end

  def wrap(&block)
    @procs << block
  end

  def execute
    original_proc = Proc.new { call_original }
    @procs.reduce(original_proc) do |memo, p|
      Proc.new { p.call &memo }
    end.call
  end

  def call_original
    puts 'in the middle'
  end
end

spy = Spy.new
spy.wrap do |&block|
  puts 'hello'
  block.call
end
spy.wrap do |&block|
  block.call
  puts 'goodbye'
end
spy.execute
```

What I'd like to do though is remove the `|&block|` and `block.call` from my API and use `yield` instead.

```
spy.wrap do
  puts 'hello'
  yield
end
```

This didn't work and raised a `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)` error.

I've also tried creating methods by passing the proc the `define_singleton_method` in the reduce, but I haven't had any luck.

```
def execute
  original_proc = Proc.new { call_original }
  @procs.reduce(original_proc) do |memo, p|
    define_singleton_method :hello, &p
    Proc.new { singleton_method(:hello).call(&memo) }
  end.call
end
```

Is there another approach I can use? Is there anyway to `yield` from a Proc or use the Proc to initialize something that can be yielded to?

Answer (score 1):

Using `yield` in your wrap block does not make much sense unless you passed a block to the caller itself:

```
def foo
  spy.wrap do
    puts "executed in wrap from foo"
    yield
  end
end
```

If you call `foo` without a block it will raise the exception since `yield` can't find a block to execute. But if you pass a block to `foo` method then it will be invoked:

```
foo do
  puts "foo block"
end
```

Will output

```
executed in wrap from foo
foo block
```

In conclusion I think you misunderstood how `yield` works and I don't think it is what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is curry each block passed to `wrap` with a aggregate block that wraps all of the rest of the calls to the `wrap` method. I figured I could 1) capture the block passed to `wrap` to a proc, 2) store those for delayed execution, 3) execute and chain each of the stored procs, each wrapping one another. It would be syntactically nicer to get this working with yield I think. Not going to spend much more time on it

Comment: More succinctly, it doesn't seem that I can take a block with a `yield`, pass that into some builder method, and use that block to create a method that will `yield`

Comment: If you wish to manipulate blocks, you can't work around the `yield` keyword